# jQuery - iterate through links, open

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

Is it possible to have a bookmarklet to open all URLs on a page containing some unique href? (like *aggregator/h* or something, preferably not complicated regex). I'm looking at jQuery.each + window.open (Firefox is set to have all new windows open in tabs, popupblocker disabled) but can't figure out how to do the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`attribute contains selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
$('a[href*="aggregator/h"]').each(function(){
    window.open(this.href);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Knew it was easy, didn't know it was that easy. Will accept when the timer is up.

Comment: @jmoon How could I modify this code to open the links in new tabs?

Comment: @synaptik this should open in new tabs/windows

Comment: @MichaelRobinson it always opens in new windows. It's very cool, but I'm trying to figure out how to force it into new tabs, not windows. (Using Google Chrome.)

Comment: How could I specify a regular expression instead of `"aggregator/h"`?